# J-Meter if value does not exist in CSV omit it entirely in POST

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have four variables:

url

uuid

affiliate_type

custom_url

Example of line from csv(\t delimited)

1) http://home.com/home123:F7zBnMyn0Lo   shomei   3   http://home.net

2) http://home2.com/defjkl456   sshomei 4

Requests:

1.) POST data:
url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.com%2Fhome123%3AF7zBnMyn0Lo+&uuid=sshomei&affiliate_type=3&**custom_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome**

2.) POST data:
url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome2.com%2Fdefjkl456&uuid=sshomei&affiliate_type=4&**custom_url=**

My main question is, is there a simple way to remove &custom_url= entirely if **no value** exists? I have massive files with millions of requests that I need to test. I would prefer not to break up the files based off how many variables they have.

Thank you for your time,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct you url the next way: http%3A%2F%2Fhome.com%2Fhome123%3AF7zBnMyn0Lo+&uuid=sshomei&affiliate_type=3${CUSTOM_URL} where CUSTOM URL is user defined variable. In PreProcessor you can compare whether custom url read from file equals empty string

```
if(targetString.equals(''))
{
   vars.putObject("CUSTOM_URL",'');
}
else 
{
   vars.putObject("CUSTOM_URL",valueReadFromCSV.toString());
}
```

Comment: This is of great help. I am just not sure what preprocessor to use(JDBC, BSF, JSR223, beanshell?). In beanshell I tried setting my parameters to be passed to be ${custom_url} and custom_url. Do you have to tell the thread group to use the preprocessor? Sorry for the questions. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: I personally prefer using BSFPreprocessor because it allows me to write scripts using Groovy language. You can use your favorite language if you add needed jar into lib directory. BeanShell PreProcessor allows you to write code using java without adding additional jars. I assume that you use http request, so add PreProcessor to that request.

Comment: I am reading each line from a text file using the CSV data set config attribute. I totally understand what you are saying to do, but still lost such as where to add PreProcessor to that request etc.Thank you so much for your help. Here are my settings http://imgur.com/a/FccKf

Comment: I meant that CUSTOM_URL is user defined variable http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables but I see no such element in your test plan. I bet you get an exception if open error log (click the yellow triangle with exclamation mar -- it is in right upper corner)

Comment: I would ideally not like to have to define thousands of user defined variables. Each URL either has a custom_url or does not. I really want a way for the URL to be built based on if the field is there on the csv line or it is not.


`http://test.com/test123:F7zBnMyn0Lo  sstesti 3 http://test`


`http://test2.com/defjkl456 sstesti 4 `